# Refreshing List Control with F5 key press C++

Tags: c++, mfc, key-events, listcontrol

I have a List Control that shows a list of my database users.  I also have a function that refreshes the list control (currently it is mapped to a "Refresh" button).

*When the user presses the "F5" key, I want to call my refresh function.*

I have found an event **LVN_KEYDOWN** (Indicates that a key has been pressed).  After some research, I have found that the virtual keycode for "F5" is `VK_F5`.  I am having trouble putting the two together, how can I check to see (in my event) that the "F5" key was the one that was pressed?  I have tried several things similar to the code below:

```
void ListOption::OnLvnKeydownList1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMLVKEYDOWN pLVKeyDow = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLVKEYDOWN>(pNMHDR);

    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    if(pLVKeyDow == (LPNMLVKEYDOWN)VK_F5)  
        callRefreshFunction();

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wVKey` member contains the virtual key code:

```
if(pLVKeyDow->wVKey == VK_F5) {
    callRefreshFunction();
    *rResult = 1;
}
```

According to comments on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you have to set the return value to 1
if you handle the message.